# Make large matrix to smaller with mask

Tags: matrix, pytorch, torch

I have a tensor A (M x N x C) and mask(M x N) for tensor A.

Due to memory issue for my transformer network, I want to make a small tensor by taking only the part defined by the mask from tensor A.

For example, Figure 1 is my tensor A. I paint gray for masked query-key pair.
[image: Figure 1. tensor A]
**Figure 1. example for tensor A**

I don't need gray colored value for further calculation. So I want to make smaller tensor including all required value.

From Figure 1 tensor, I hope to make tensor like Figure 2. In Figure 2, gray colored value is just dummy value, and whether the index of corresponding value is a dummy value can be known through the mask.(Figure 3)

[image]

**Figure 2. smaller tensor**

[image]

**Figure 3. Mask indicating index of dummy value filled**

How can I do this with efficient torch operation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [sparse](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html) tensors. Sparse representation does not give you a "packed" matrix with "dummy" values, but rather a different way of storing only those entires you care about.
Pytorch also support some operations on sparse matrices.